# How to run an Erlang project in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, erlang

I am new to Erlang and trying to run some sample projects to know the control flow of building the project. But am unable to that. I cloned some projects and the project is automatically build. Now how am i supposed to run the project/application? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

In the article
[Erlang – Getting Started and Using Eclipse](https://myadventuresincoding.wordpress.com/2009/02/11/erlang-getting-started-and-using-eclipse/)
there are detailed instructions in setting up an Erlang project in Eclipse.
Verify that your settings are the same, and especially the Run settings.

I quote that part of the article having to do with the Run environment:

> 1. Run -> Run Configurations
> 2. Right click on “Erlang Application” and select “New”
> 3. In the first tab titled “Main” select your project “HelloWorld”
> 4. On the tab “Runtimes” ensure
>
>    ```
>    Runtime = Erlang
>    Node name = erlide
>    ```
> 5. Now for the most important part, go to the “Environment” tab
>
>    ```
>    Click “Select”
>    select “PATH”
>    click “OK”
>    ```
> 6. Now click “Apply” and close the window